# Camera Warning - Augmented Reality

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, augmented-reality, appstore-approval

I built an app that contains Augmented Reality feature when user taps a button. Camera opens without a message that phone's camera will be used. I submitted my app recently and i am waiting for review. Is this a problem that may cause app rejection from Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the camera usage needs a permission? As far as I remember it's only needed for saving to the `Albums` app. Anyway, if you're using standard controls like `UIImagePickerView` you shouldn't worry.

Comment: I use AVCaptureSession etc.